# Body tag non behaving normally

Tags: html, css

I have a `body` tag in my HTML which should fill the whole page (the whole `html` tag so), but it appears with some pixels between the top of the page and the top of the `body` tag.

Strange thing is that if I force `body {padding: 0;}` in my CSS, there's still this little bar at the top of the page which `body` doesn't manage to fill, while if I set `padding` to any non-zero value that little bar gets covered by `body` and the specified padding is applied.

This is my trivial CSS (which styles a `body` HTML tag filled with `div`s and ordinary stuff):

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; // this is ok, html fills the whole page
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 1px; // here, if I write padding:0;, space at the top will not be filled by body
}
```

#### Edit

Here's my HTML, I don't know if it can be useful.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">

    <header id="page_header">
        stuff
    </header>

    <section id="page_content">
        stuff
    </section>    

    <footer id="page_footer">
        stuff
    </footer>

    </div> <!-- end of div#container -->
</body>
```

**Note**: I'm working with both Firefox and Chrome, same behavior.

Comment: Do you have any HTML to go with that CSS?

Comment: Just try with *{padding:0}  instead of body{}.  This is because the space you mention is technically outside the body.

Comment: @Ryoku tried with that too, didn't change.

Comment: Your margins from your content are collapsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try clearing both of the html and body tag CSS rules, and simply put:

```
/* basic CSS reset */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```